# Completely custom tab bar Transition in UITabbarController + UINavigationController

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a (subclass of) UITabbarController with 4 tabs, every tab has a (subclass of) UINavigationController with a 3+ levels view controllers navigation hierarchy.

The tab bar is visible only in each UINavigationController root view controller.

When the UINavigationController pushes the second level view controller the tab bar slides out correctly with the root view controller:

[image: Standard tab bar animation when pushed]

Until here no problem, everything is correct.

**Step 2, completely custom Tab Bar**

I have implemented a floating tab bar (subclass of UIView not UITabBar), added the tab bar to the UITabbarController view (note: the default tab bar is added to the same view) but the behaviour when the navigation controller pushes the second navigation level is different, the tab bar remain visible :

[image: Custom tab bar animation when pushed]

Obviously the UINavigationController manage the standard tab bar and move it with the root view controller, any idea how to replicate this behaviour with my custom tab bar? I'm looking for a smart and reusable way, not do it manually in each root view controller.

Additionally I have created a MyTabBar : UITabBar class and changed the class type of the UITabbarController navigationBar in the Storyboard in order to intercept the setHidden method and hide my custom tab bar:

```
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    if (hidden)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNOTIF_TabBarNotificationHideBar object:nil];
    else
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNOTIF_TabBarNotificationShowBar object:nil];

    [super setHidden:YES];
}
```

that works correctly.